# Running dotnet core 2.2 app as service WITHOUT Exe file

Tags: .net-core

Is it possible to run a .NET Core application as a service without having it published as an EXE file?

My requirement can be satisfied by doing this; I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this or is there anything in the pipeline to enable this feature in the future?

In an ideal world I'd like to create a service to target a .DLL rather than a .EXE so when I publish my app(s) I don't need to export run times along with with them as it results in a very messy folder with a lot of files that aren't required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you need with Azure Webjobs. Please read the following link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/app-service/webjobs-create?view=netcore-1.0

I have several webjobs that each one calls a different DLL, and you can invoke them manually or periodically (using a schedule)